# Power scheme not applying in Group Policy

Tags: windows-xp, power-management, group-policy

I've created a new GPO and created a power scheme under computer configuration. I've disabled the User configuration part of this GPO.

In this power scheme I have the action selected to create a new power scheme, I've input all my settings and ticked the box "Make this the active power Scheme" but this power scheme never appears on the targeted systems.

If I perform a gpresult /scope:computer on the target system I can see that the GPO is applied.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power Schemes in **Windows XP** are only applied to the user account, not the computer account.

> Windows XP only has one active power scheme for the entire computer
>   and that scheme is based on the current or previously logged on user

and

> A Power Option preference item applying to a Windows XP computer does
>   two things: it changes the power settings in the .DEFAULT profile and
>   it makes those new settings the active power profile. A Power Option
>   preference item applying to a user does two things: It changes the
>   power settings in that user’s profile and it makes those new settings
>   the active power profile. Remember there is only one active power
>   profile—it’s the profile that was last made active.

From: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/12/11/windows-xp-power-management-and-group-policy-preferences.aspx